# Tile Multiple forms on Desktop in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, tile

I have a program that opens some secondary forms.  I want tile all then instances of Form2 on the desktop.

I am not using MDI Layout.

```
For X = 1 To Updown1.Value
    Dim form As New Form2
    form.Text = "Sample Table " + X.ToString
    form.Show()
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Windows API for this.  Here's some sample code here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.tilewindows